# How to disable cache during memory test in uboot

Tags: caching, u-boot, mmu

I need to write a memory test in uboot but need to disable the cache. I know we can configure the p15 c1 to disable the data cache and MMU entirely, but that seems to be too dangerous. Is there any more elegant way to do that? Like setting an attribute during memory mapping?

I was also told that for commands in uboot, the cache is probably already disabled, but I just can't prove it... Any one can help? Thanks

Comment: Just find a series of functions such as dcache_enable(), dcache_disable()... but still interested if we can set some attribute to some memory area instead of using this.

Comment: *"I need to write a memory test*" -- Have you looked at the 2 versions that already exist in U-Boot?  *"...but need to disable the cache"* -- That is hardware specific, and you haven't mentioned anything about that.  Normally a reset MMU would disable almost everything, and code would have to explicitly enable a feature such as cache.  So normally there is no reason to disable something that has not been enabled.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, Uboot already has API to disable cache for the whole system. What I'm looking for now is a way to disable the cache for some region of the memory, such as setting a bit in that memory page. I believe Uboot should have that since for IO memory, the cache should be disabled.